# How would you explain the concept of classes and objects to a non-programmer with a neat example from real world to programming representation?

Tags: oop, class, object

In the process of interview answers like state and behavior of data is data member and methods respectively. This kind of answers will not be appreciated ! So is there anyway i can explain people in really easy way and catchy.!!! ??

Comment: Examples with kittens are clear ALWAYS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example from Java for Dummies [Link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/refining-your-understanding-of-classes-and-objects.html):

"Take a minute to look around your room. (If you're not sitting in a room right now, fake it.)

Several chairs are in the room, and each chair is an object. Each of these objects is an example of that ethereal thing called the Chair class. So that's how it works — the class is the idea of chairness, and each individual chair is an object.

A class isn't quite a collection of things. Instead, a class is the idea behind a certain kind of thing. When we talk about the class of chairs in your room, we're talking about the fact that each chair has legs, a seat, a color, and so on. The colors may be different for different chairs in the room, but that doesn't matter. When you talk about a class of things, you're focusing on the properties that each of the things possesses.

It makes sense to think of an object as being a concrete instance of a class. In fact, the official terminology is consistent with this thinking. If you write a Java program in which you define a Chair class, each actual chair (the chair that you're sitting on, the empty chair right next to you, and so on) is called an instance of the Chair class."

Answer (score 0):

I have used an exercise about Taxi Cabs as a good example of OOP and classes.  You have a Taxi interface that has some data object to contain its passengers and its destination and maybe some helper methods for the cab driver (getter/setter destination, calculate $).  You can then implement it using different classes of taxi to give different functionality.

- A small cab has an array that can only fit X people and only 1 destination.
- A larger cab has a list to store more passengers
- Bus can hold a lot more people, and can have multiple spots.

You can tailor the different cabs to meet the stuff you are trying to explain.  You can make them different colors to add more properties to customize when you "initialize" a cab, you can have different overridden functions of deciding which stop along a route is the next one the cab gets (so the driver knows where to go), etc.